# Showing Bernoulli function is constant on streamlines

Tags: fluid-dynamics

An incompressible inviscid ﬂuid, under the inﬂuence of gravity, has the velocity ﬁeld
$$\textbf u = (− \cos(x)\sin(y), \, \, \sin(x)\cos(y), \, \, 0)$$
with the $z$-axis vertically upwards, where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Show that the Bernoulli function $H = p/ρ + \textbf{u}^2/2 + gz$ is constant on the streamlines.

I got the pressure as $$p= - \frac{\rho}4 \bigg( \cos (2x) + \cos (2y) \bigg) - \rho g z$$ and the equations of streamlines as $$ \cos (x) \cos (y) = A $$ where $A$ is a constant.
Then $H$ becomes $$H =- \frac{1}4 \bigg( \cos (2x) + \cos (2y) \bigg) + \frac12 \bigg( \cos ^2 (x) \sin ^2 (y) + \sin^2 (x) \cos ^2 (y) \bigg)$$
but I can't get it in the form of the streamline equations.

Comment: Do you know double angle formulae?

Comment: Yh I did a lot of messing around but can't see how it can be turned into the streamline equations...

Comment: sorry i thought it was something else when i did the math in my head!

Comment: I wrote the wrong streamline equations...

Comment: Why is this an exact duplicate of a question asked from a different user account less than two days prior? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641862/prove-bernoulli-function-is-constant-on-streamline

Answer (score -1):

When you have ln|cos(x)|=ln|sec(x)+c, try making everything to the power of e. You will get cos(x)+cos(y)=A. Are these your new streamlines?

Comment: Edited to improve

Comment: I'm sure its cos(x)cos(y)=A isn't it?

Comment: But you said you wrote the wrong streamlines?